# Контейнер map STL C++

Tags: c++, stl

Допустим в контейнере `map` хранится один ключ. Что будет, если мы добавим еще один ключ с таким же именем, что и в первом ключе? Выкинет исключение?

Comment: Не выкинет, перезапишет значение ключа.

Comment: Это как?

      Because element keys in a map are unique, the insertion operation checks whether each inserted element has a key equivalent to the one of an element already in the container, and if so, the element is not inserted, returning an iterator to this existing element (if the function returns a value).

Answer (score 1):

Дельный совет - пробуй сам написать коротенький тестик: ты и ответ узнаешь, и сам попрактикуешься немного:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

template<typename T1, typename T2>
void printMap(const std::map<T1, T2>& container)
{
    std::cout << "Container size = " << container.size() << std::endl;
    for(typename std::map<T1, T2>::value_type item : container) {
        std::cout << "key = " << item.first << " val = " << item.second << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    std::map<std::string, int> myMap;

    myMap.insert(std::make_pair("key1", 50));
    printMap(myMap);

    myMap.insert(std::make_pair("key1", 100));
    printMap(myMap);

    myMap["key1"] = 300;
    printMap(myMap);
}
```

Result:

```
Container size = 1
key = key1 val = 50 
Container size = 1
key = key1 val = 50 
Container size = 1
key = key1 val = 300
```

Видно что map::insert() не изменит значение по имеющемуся ключу, map::operator[] перезапишет значение